# Prove that if $AA^{*}$ is Orthogonal $\Rightarrow$ A is Orthogonal. ($A\in\mathbb{R}_{nxn}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, orthogonal-matrices

> > Prove that if $AA^{*}$ is Orthogonal $\Rightarrow$ A is Orthogonal. ($A\in\mathbb{R}_{nxn}$)

I should probably state that the first thing I did was to prove $AA^*$ is self-adjoint and all eigenvalues are non-negative.

Here's my approach:

$AA^{*}$ is Orthogonal, so $(AA^{*})\cdot(AA^{*})^{*}=(AA^{*})^2=I$.

so $(AA^{*})^2-I=0$ $\Rightarrow (AA^{*}+I)\cdot(AA^{*}-I)=0$

if $(AA^{*}+I)=0$ then $AA^*=-I$ but $AA^*$ is a positive matrix.

so $AA^*-I=0 \Rightarrow AA^*=I \Rightarrow A^*=A^{-1} \Rightarrow A$ is Orthogonal.

does it make sense?

thanks!

Comment: Hello :) I don't get the second line. Does from $B^2-I=0$ follows $B-I=0$ or $B+I=0$? I expect that to be false. Maybe take a permutation matrix that represents a transposition.

Comment: You are right. that's exactly what @user1551 and Ben Grossman said. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof can be corrected by noting that $AA^\ast+I$ is positive definite and hence nonsingular. Therefore $(AA^\ast+I)(AA^\ast-I)=0$ implies that $AA^\ast-I=0$.

Comment: nonsigular = invertible? just to be sure.

Comment: @OacRoland Over a field (such as in the current case), yes. In general, over a commutative ring, invertible implies nonsingular but the converse is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is not correct because $(B - I)(B + I) = 0$ does **not** imply that $B = -I$ or $B = I$.

Instead, simply note that $(A^*A)$ is a self-adjoint matrix with positive eigenvalues for which $(A^*A)^2 = I$. Show that if $B^2 = I$, then any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$ must satisfy $\lambda^2 = 1$. From the positivity of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$, we know that all eigenvalues are equal to $1$.  Because self-adjoint operators are diagonalizable (by the spectral theorem), we can conclude from this that $A^*A = I$.

Comment: Thank you so much! got it.